# mysql POINT column - trying to set up a new field

Tags: mysql, spatial

I'm trying to update my script so that it uses a **POINT** value instead of a Latitude/Longitude column, to try and help with my geo searches (distance ranges). So I have this column:

```
`point_test` point DEFAULT NULL
```

..and I'm trying to set it with:

```
UPDATE glinks_Links SET 
    point_test = POINT(52.35462 4.88227) WHERE ID = 3693134
```

but it gives a mySQL error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '4.88227) WHERE ID = 3693134' at line 2
```

I found a blog post about Spatial points, and it suggested running this:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ST_SPATIAL_REFERENCE_SYSTEMS
```

But I get this error:

```
#1109 - Unknown table 'ST_SPATIAL_REFERENCE_SYSTEMS' in information_schema
```

Do I need to turn on spatials in the mysql.conf file maybe?

FYI I'm running **mySQL Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.27**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your update statement you've missed a comma. The query should be as follows, with comma between longitute and latitude:

```
UPDATE glinks_Links SET point_test = POINT(52.35462, 4.88227) WHERE ID = 3693134;
```

Comment: OMG now I feel like a muppet! Funny thing, is that I took the value from phpmyadmin's suggestion (when manually adding a row): https://ibb.co/6BxD6FH . Putting the comma in, and voila... it works now :) Thanks!